# django rest framework annotate with ArrayAgg and GROUP BY

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I would like to use the django postgres function ArrayAgg, but I would like to also use it with GROUP BY as well.  The sql is really easy to write, but I have not been able to get it to work with the ORM or raw sql

```
SELECT field1, ARRAY_AGG(field2)
FROM table1
GROUP BY field1
```

with the orm I would think something like this might work

```
subquery = Subquery(
           models.Model1.objects
           .filter(field1=OuterRef('field1'))
           .values('field2')
           .aggregate(field3=ArrayAgg('field2'))
           .values('field3')
)
queryset = queryset.annotate(field3=subquery)
```

But it doesn't with a outerref error (I have tried many permutations)

and with a raw query I can get it to work, but then it returns all the fields I am guessing due to the RawQueryset and things like defer doesn't work so all fields are queried and returned.

```
rawqueryset = models.Model1.objects.raw(
    'SELECT m.id, t.field1, t.field3 '
    'FROM ('
        'SELECT field1, array_agg(field2) as field3 '
        'FROM app_table1 '
        'GROUP BY frame_id '
    ') t LEFT OUTER JOIN app_table m ON m.field1 = t.frame_id',
    []
)
serializer = serializers.Model1(rawqueryset, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using raw sql

```
rawqueryset = models.Model1.objects.raw(
    'SELECT m.id, t.field1, t.field3 '
    'FROM ('
        'SELECT field1, array_agg(field2) as field3 '
        'FROM app_table1 '
        'GROUP BY frame_id '
    ') t LEFT OUTER JOIN app_table m ON m.field1 = t.frame_id',
    []
)
serializer = serializers.Model1(rawqueryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
return Response(serializer.data)
```

What was missing was adding the request object to the passed context.